# why the data is not stored in GemfireXD just like input file?

Tags: apache-spark, in-memory-database, hana, gemfire, geode

iam loading data in to GemfireXD from a file ....
file contain the information like this...
ID         NAME
1         |John Smth
2         |Jane
3         |Paul Joes
4         |Mark Jcobs
5         |Mary Sphenson
6         |Steve oberts
7         |Margaret Johnso

AFTER LOADING THE DATA IN TO GemfireXD ,if you fire query SELECT * FROM TABLE Output is like this ....

ID          NAME
5         |Mary Sphenson
7         |Margaret Johnso
4         |Mark Jcobs
2         |Jane
3         |Paul Joes
1         |John Smth
6         |Steve oberts

many i know the reason why the ID  are notstored in a proper order like INPUT File

help on this....

Thanku You

Answer (score 2):

Well, this has nothing to do with GemFireXD as such but basic SQL.  Results of a select are not required to be ordered unless you specify an "order by" clause.  Add "order by".